# Authtificate using the access token symfony

Tags: symfony, authentication, access-token

I search for a solution to authtificate using the access token,
The customer sends a link via email https://www.mywebsite.com/?token=ijn8pC5q2bwftM7dMcjkhkdhgkfdjgfdgg type). when the customer click on the link, the applciation should get automatically the token and then redirect the user his personal page,
Any idea please

Comment: FOSUser does something very similar to this when resetting the password (sends a mail with a token). Take a look at the `resetAction()` method on `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Controller/ResettingController.php` to take some inspiration :)

Comment: Every app has its own requisite, of course, but still be mindful that unless it's a one-time token, this would give someone immediate access to the user's account as long as they get that email/token. Also, if you don't plan on limiting tries on any way, people could brute-force try to access your app by generating random tokens and trying until they find someone's token.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using an custom **authentication guard**. This well described in the [documentation of symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/guard-authentication.html#step-1-create-the-authenticator-class). In the example they use an http header field, but you can easily use a query parameter to do the same thing.

As Daniel commented, be aware of token invalidation to ensure a secure application.